# Thymeleaf: Exception processing template "index": Template mode "LEGACYHTML5 " has not been configured

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using SpringBoot + Thymeleaf and I am trying to switch the mode to LEGACYHTML. I added the following line to my `application.properties`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception processing template "index": Template mode "LEGACYHTML5 " has not been configured
```

I hope that someone could help me :l.
Thanks you for your time

Comment: what version of Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. I dont really know what was happening but i erased the line of my aplication.properties, i wrote it again and it worked. 
Thanks you for editing my question hehe i am kinda new on this

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me.
It must be the caused by the space char after the "LEGACYHTML5".
Deleting the space char in config file fixed the problem.